# Is it possible to make an application on the market to be available only to specific users or devices?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an application for an in-house use of a company and shouldn't be available for the open public.

The obvious publishing option would be to put my application in my own website, but I would like to use the market updating capabilities and save the user from enabling "Allow installation from non-market applications".

Is it possible to publish the application on the market, but make it available only to a specific list of accounts or devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible in that way but you can go ahead and put in licensing services... :)
That way you'll be able to control who can install the application.

Comment: As I read, licensing services applies only to paid application, right?
Could I restrict who could buy the application (by device or account)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to exclude devices by type (i.e. you can e.g. exclude Samsung Galaxy S2 users).
You can also set the language for which your application is available. By specifying minSdkVersion and supported screens sizes in your manifest you can exclude some devices to. But apart from that there is not much you can do.